# Display a particular widget only on posts which have a particular label on blogger

Tags: xml, lambda, widget, blogger

There are a number of posts with "label1". Those posts have may labels like "label1", "Label2" etc.

The widget in question ,must appear for a post, only if it has a label called "label1".

I tried achieving the above using lambda expression as below, in a typical way of displaying/hiding conditions for widgets:

```
<b:widget id='HTML38' locked='false' title='' type='HTML' version='1' visible='true'>
<b:includable id='main'>
<!-- only display title if it's non-empty -->
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "item"'>
<b:if cond='data:post.labels any (label => label.name == "label1")'>
<b:if cond='data:title != &quot;&quot;'>
<h2 class='title'><data:title/></h2>
</b:if>
<div class='widget-content'>
<data:content/>
</div>

<b:include name='quickedit'/>
<b:else/>
/* Thing to do otherwise */
</b:if>
</b:if>
```

But, it doesn't show that widget for any posts, even for posts with the desired "label1".

Is this achievable using lambda expressions, or by some other means?
If it is, then is it possible to have a widget appear for any of "label1" or "label2"

Am quite new to xml & coding, & would appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data:post.labels` inside the blog widget only as mentioned in the [Layouts Data Tags](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/47270#posts). To do that use javascript tricks.